# Run member function of an object contained in an arraylist?

Tags: c#

Basically I have an arraylist of different types of objects that all have a Draw() function. I want to use a loop to run the draw function of each object. But C# tells me that type "object" doesn't have that function. Any idea's for a lowly n00b?

Comment: Use a generic collection which has been available since .NET 2.

Answer (score 3):

That `Draw` method should be defined in an interface:

```
public interface IDrawable 
{
    void Draw();
}
```

All your other classes (with a `.Draw` method) should implement this interface.  And your list should be a `List<IDrawable>`.  Then you can simply invoke the `.Draw` method on each item as expected:

```
List<IDrawable> list = new ...;
foreach (var item in list) 
{
    item.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using .NET 1.1, you shouldn't really be using the `ArrayList`.

If you're talking about UI elements, they should all implement the `IDrawable` interface. If they're your custom type, you too should implement the `IDrawable` interface on those classes. You can then use a generic `List<T>` to store them.

```
List<IDrawable> objects = new List<IDrawable>();

// Fill the list

// Iterate over each object and call Draw()
foreach(IDrawable obj in objects)
{
    obj.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They should all implement an IDrawable interface. and your arraylist will probably want to contain a list of IDrawable rather than object.

Answer (score 0):

If they share a common interface you can cast to that interface.

If the number of types are known and fixed, try to cast to each of the known types with [`AS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator.

Otherwise you'll have to resort to reflection, something like this

```
for (i...){
    object oneObject = arrayList[i];
    Type objectType = oneObject.GetType();
    objectType.GetMethod("Draw").Invoke(oneObject, new object[0]);
}
```

But if you need to resort to reflection that is a huge code smell and should really be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

With an `ArrayList` all of the elements are stored as the type `Object`.  To call a function defined on antother type you'd first need to cast the members to that type.

```
class MyType { 
  public void Draw() {
    ...
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++) {
  MyType current = (MyType)arrayList[i];
  current.Draw();
}
```

This code only works though if the objects stored in the `ArrayList` are convertible to `MyType`.  If you're using .Net 2.0 or later then avoid `ArrayList` entirely and instead use `List<MyType>`.  This is a strongly typed collection and avoids the need for a cast at all.

```
List<MyType> list = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
  list[i].Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 4 or better, you can use the dynamic type for this:

```
foreach (dynamic obj in arrayList)
    obj.Draw();
```

This will fail at runtime if you have an object whose type lacks a matching `Draw()` signature.

If you're using an earlier version of C#, you can use reflection.

Having said that, you really ought not to be using `ArrayList` unless you're forced to by some legacy library.  The more idiomatic solution, as others suggest, is to have an `IDrawable` interface and a `List<IDrawable>`.

Comment: Under no circumstance should this solution be one's first choice.

Comment: @KirkWoll I disagree.  I would use this solution if I didn't have control over the arrayList, or of the types of its contents, for example, if these were returned by a call to a legacy library.

Comment: I've yet to encounter a scenario where using a 3rd party library forced me to abandon type safety.  There are lots of [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to address this sort of problem without resorting to an abandonment of the static type system.  In any case, we're hardly disagreeing -- I said this shouldn't be your *first* choice, as in, if you have control over the code.

Comment: @KirkWoll correct; I agree in general.  The part I disagreed with was "under no circumstances".  Granted, these are circumstances which I've also never encountered, but I've worked on projects where it would not be surprising to encounter them.